# SuperResolution using MNIST not working properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am new to Deep Learning and I made a model that pretends to upscale a 14x14 image to a 28x28. For that, I trained the newtork using MNIST repository as a first attempt to solve this problem.

For making the model structure I followed this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.00367.pdf

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
import os
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import time

# Tensorboard Stuff:
NAME = "MNIST_FSRCNN_test -{}".format(
    int(time.time()))  # This is the name of our try, change it if it's a
# new try.
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(NAME))  # defining tensorboard directory.

# Path of the data
train_small_path = "D:/MNIST/training/small_train"
train_normal_path = "D:/MNIST/training/normal_train"

test_small_path = "D:/MNIST/testing/small_test"
test_normal_path = "D:/MNIST/testing/normal_test"

# Image reading from the directories. MNIST is in grayscale so we read it that way.
train_small_array = []
for img in os.listdir(train_small_path):
    try:
        train_small_array.append(np.array(cv2.imread(os.path.join(train_small_path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)))
    except Exception as e:
        print("problem with image reading in train small")
        pass
train_normal_array = []
for img in os.listdir(train_normal_path):
    try:
        train_normal_array.append(np.array(cv2.imread(os.path.join(train_normal_path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)))
    except Exception as e:
        print("problem with image reading in train normal")
        pass
test_small_array = []
for img in os.listdir(test_small_path):
    try:
        test_small_array.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(test_small_path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
    except Exception as e:
        print("problem with image reading in test small")
        pass

test_normal_array = []
for img in os.listdir(test_normal_path):
    try:
        test_normal_array.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(test_normal_path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
    except Exception as e:
        print("problem with image reading in test normal")
        pass

train_small_array = np.array(train_small_array).reshape((60000, 14, 14, 1))
train_normal_array = np.array(train_normal_array).reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1))

test_small_array = np.array(test_small_array).reshape((10000, 14, 14, 1))
test_normal_array = np.array(test_normal_array).reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))




training_data = []
training_data.append([train_small_array, train_normal_array])

testing_data = []
testing_data.append([test_small_array, test_normal_array])


# ---SAVE DATA--
# We are saving our data
pickle_out = open("X.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
# for reading it:
pickle_in = open("X.pickle", "rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)
# -----------


# MAKING THE NETWORK
d = 56
s = 12
m = 4
upscaling = 2

model = models.Sequential()
bias = True

# Feature extraction:
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=d,
                        kernel_size=5,
                        padding='SAME',
                        data_format="channels_last",
                        use_bias=bias,
                        kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(),
                        input_shape=(None, None, 1),
                        activation='relu'))

# Shrinking:
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=s,
                        kernel_size=1,
                        padding='same',
                        use_bias=bias,
                        kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(),
                        activation='relu'))

for i in range(m):
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=s,
                            kernel_size=3,
                            padding="same",
                            use_bias=bias,
                            kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(),
                            activation='relu'),
              )

# Expanding
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=d,
                        kernel_size=1,
                        padding='same',
                        use_bias=bias,
                        kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal,
                        activation='relu'))

# Deconvolution
model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=1,
                                 kernel_size=9,
                                 strides=(upscaling, upscaling),
                                 padding='same',
                                 use_bias=bias,
                                 kernel_initializer=initializers.random_normal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.001),
                                 activation='relu'))

# MODEL COMPILATION
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3),  
              metrics=['acc'])




model.fit(x=train_small_array, y=train_normal_array,
          epochs=10,
          batch_size=1500,
          validation_split=0.2,
          callbacks=[tensorboard])


print(model.evaluate(test_small_array, test_normal_array))



# -DEMO-----------------------------------------------------------------
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps
import os

dir = 'C:/Users/marcc/OneDrive/Escritorio'
os.chdir(dir)

myImage = Image.open("ImageTest.PNG").convert('L')  # convert to black and white
myImage = myImage.resize((14, 14))


myImage_array = np.array(myImage)

plt.imshow(myImage_array, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()

myImage_array = myImage_array.astype('float32') / 255
myImage_array = myImage_array.reshape(1, 14, 14, 1)



newImage = model.predict(myImage_array)
newImage = newImage.reshape(28,28)
plt.imshow(newImage, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
```

The problem that I have is that with 10 epochs it seems to work, it transforms this image:[14x14 MNIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWdZe.png)

into this one:
[10 epochs 28x28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cshDx.png)

But when I make 20 epochs I get[20 epochs 28x28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AOhu.png)

I want to know what happens. First I thought that maybe the model was overfitting, but when I check the loss function of training and validation it doesn't seem to overfit:
[training and validation loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou8da.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code and tried to reproduce the error, but it worked fine for me.
I loaded the mnist images and resized them to `(14, 14)` using `skimage.transform.resize`.
The training during 200 epochs gives :

> Epoch 1/200 32/32 - 6s 91ms/step -
> loss: 4380.9126 - acc: 0.1659 - val_loss: 3406.4109 - val_acc: 0.3661
> Epoch 2/200 32/32 - 3s 80ms/step -
> loss: 2827.0591 - acc: 0.5598 - val_loss: 2255.1472 - val_acc: 0.6366
> ...
> Epoch 199/200 32/32 - 3s
> 86ms/step - loss: 149.0597 - acc: 0.8035 - val_loss: 191.1202 -
> val_acc: 0.8072
> Epoch 200/200 32/32 -
> 3s 85ms/step - loss: 145.8007 - acc: 0.8035 - val_loss: 207.3333 -
> val_acc: 0.8072

`val_loss` tends to fluctuate between epochs but it decreases globally.
Some results : [image: here]

Here is the code to plot the figures:

```
     def plot_images(num_img):
      fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
      my_normal_image = test_normal_array[num_img, :, :, 0]
      axs[0, 0].set(title='input normal image')
      axs[0, 0].imshow(my_normal_image, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
      axs[1, 0].set(title = 'small img')
      my_resized_image = resize(my_normal_image, anti_aliasing=True, output_shape=(14, 14))
      axs[1, 0].imshow(my_resized_image, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
      axs[0, 1].set(title='super resolution')
      my_super_res_image = model.predict(my_resized_image[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis])[0, :, :, 0]
      axs[0, 1].imshow(my_super_res_image, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
      axs[1, 1].set(title='small resized')
      my_rr_image = resize(my_resized_image, output_shape=(28, 28), anti_aliasing=True)
      axs[1, 1].imshow(my_rr_image, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
      plt.show()

    index = 8
    plot_images(np.argwhere(y_test==index)[0][0])
    index = 4
    plot_images(np.argwhere(y_test==index)[0][0])
```

In addition, here is also how I build the dataset :

```
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    train_normal_array = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=3)
    test_normal_array = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=3)
    train_small_array = np.zeros((train_normal_array.shape[0], 14, 14, 1))
    for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(train_normal_array.shape[0])):
      train_small_array[i, :, :] = resize(train_normal_array[i], (14, 14), anti_aliasing=True)
    test_small_array = np.zeros((test_normal_array.shape[0], 14, 14, 1))
    for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(test_normal_array.shape[0])):
      test_small_array[i, :, :] = resize(test_normal_array[i], (14, 14), anti_aliasing=True)
    training_data = []
    training_data.append([train_small_array.astype('float32'), train_normal_array.astype('float32') / 255])
    
    testing_data = []
    testing_data.append([test_small_array.astype('float32'), test_normal_array.astype('float32') / 255])
```

Note that I do not divide `train_small_array` and `test_small_array` by 255 as resize does the job.

Comment: Thank you a lot I might be doing something wrong with my testing. Can you post the code that you use?